# Merging multiple(1000s) large files into one file using Spring

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have 1000s of large files in a directory and i have to merge them all into a single files with a header and trailor record. Does spring provide any such functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) you can use `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>` to read those files from the directory.

On the other hand you can use `<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter>` with the `mode="APPEND"`.